# How to add rest controller to spring boot library, and use it in another application?

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on a library `xyz.jar` that needs to add a UI page with mappings like this one:

```
@RestController
public class LibCtrl {
    
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    @RequestMapping("/updateDomainList")
    String updateDomainList() {
        return "we can call a controller from another jar like this";
    }
}
```

This then needs to be called in my main springboot application, `myMainApplication.war`, so when I call

http://localhost/myMainApplication/updateDomainList

I should see

```
we can call controller from another jar like this
```

on the browser.

How can achieve this? `@Component` also did not work for me. Once it begins to work, would `@Autowired` to `JdbcTemplate` also work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a simple fix. @ComponentScan allows for multiple packages to be scanned. This made is possible for me to add my Library Packages to be managed by Spring. Just add the following to your application class.

```
@ComponentScan({"my.mainapplication.package","my.library.package"})
```